# RMSE differs substantially between forecast package and manual calculation

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I think I'm missing something very obvious here. When I calculate the RMSE on the test set in the `forecast` package, I get a very small number: 8.581624. But when I coerce the `ts` objects into `numeric` vectors, my RMSE explodes to: 51.9861.

What am I missing?

```r
library(forecast)
library(fpp2)

train <- window(ausbeer, end=c(2005,3))

fit <- auto.arima(train, lambda=0)

summary(fit)

accuracy(forecast(fit, h=20), x=tail(ausbeer,20))
# Test set RMSE 8.581624
```

But when I store the forecasts and actuals as numeric vectors, the RMSE gets whacky.

```r
test_actuals <- as.numeric(tail(ausbeer,20))
test_preds <- as.numeric(forecast(fit, h=20)$mean)

Metrics::rmse(test_actuals, test_preds)
# RMSE 51.9861
```

Visually, the numeric conversion worked appropriately.

```r
> test_actuals
 [1] 408 482 438 386 405 491 427 383 394 473 420 390 410 488 415 398 419 488 414 374
> tail(ausbeer,20)
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2005            408  482
2006  438  386  405  491
2007  427  383  394  473
2008  420  390  410  488
2009  415  398  419  488
2010  414  374          
> 
> test_preds
 [1] 478.7813 425.9601 389.2990 406.7974 480.3568 422.6604 388.2854 405.5242 478.4310 421.2396 386.9089 404.0702
[13] 476.7475 419.7445 385.5367 402.6393 475.0574 418.2569 384.1705 401.2124
>
> forecast(fit, h=20)$mean
         Qtr1     Qtr2     Qtr3     Qtr4
2005                            478.7813
2006 425.9601 389.2990 406.7974 480.3568
2007 422.6604 388.2854 405.5242 478.4310
2008 421.2396 386.9089 404.0702 476.7475
2009 419.7445 385.5367 402.6393 475.0574
2010 418.2569 384.1705 401.2124
```

Answer (score 1):

I set the wrong value for the `h` parameter in the `forecast()` function. This was the missing piece:

```r
### need to the set the correct h --
h_star <- length(ausbeer) - length(train)
# [1] 19
#### ----
```

Then this works fine.

```r
library(forecast)
library(fpp2)

train <- window(ausbeer, end=c(2005,3))

fit <- auto.arima(train, lambda=0)

summary(fit)

### need to the set the correct h --
h_star <- length(ausbeer) - length(train)
#### ----


accuracy(forecast(fit, h=h_star), x=ausbeer)
accuracy(forecast(fit, h=h_star), x=tail(ausbeer,h_star)) # equivalent
# Test set RMSE 8.581624

test_actuals <- as.numeric(tail(ausbeer,h_star))
test_preds <- as.numeric(forecast(fit, h=h_star)$mean)

Metrics::rmse(test_actuals, test_preds)
# RMSE 8.581624
```